# How can I exclude a port from the range of ephemeral ports in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, range, port, netsh

Now and then my JBoss server (the local one I use for testing) gets screwed at startup because of some other application taking some of JBoss ports. After some research I found the following article [KB2665809](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665809/en-us) but it doesn't seem to apply to Windows 7 (there's no `excludedportrange` at `netsh int ipv4 add|delete|show`). Anybody knows how to get the same or similar result in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question, I know. However, while dealing with the same issue today I discovered that the [hotfix linked with the KB2665809](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=2665809&kbln=en-US) works not only for Windows Server 2008, but also on Windows 7.